# Parent CSS (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, height, parent

There is `<dl>` with `padding-top`

```
<dl id="posters" style="padding-top: 150px;">
<dt class="active">text</dt>
<dd class="active"><a href="#"><img width="150" height="150" src="..." /></a></dd>
<dt>text 2</dt>
<dd><a href="#"><img width="150" height="250" src="..." /></a></dd>
<dt>text 3</dt>
<dd><a href="#"><img width="150" height="350" src="..." /></a></dd>
</dl>
```

The difference between images - `height`.

Trying to write a **script, which will change a `height` of the `<dl>`, when `<dd>` is clicked.**

**Height should be taken from the `height` attribute of the** `dd img`.

Tryed this, but had no luck:

```
$("#posters dt").click(function(){
        var parent_padding = $("dd").find("img").height();
        $("dd").closest("dl").css("padding-top",parent_padding);
    }).andSelf().addClass("active")});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be working for me, the padding is changed. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Works fine. Here it is on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tGT7F/  Are you sure the click event is being triggered at all?

Comment: Fixed the topic. Sorry, forgot about <a href="#"><img /></a>

Comment: The default behavior of the `a` may be firing and reloading the page. `parent()` shouldn't be the issue since the event is on the `<dd>` element. See my answer below to correct the issue if that is what it is.

Comment: @David Murdoch, tryed this, doesn't work. My code seems to have some initial bug http://jsbin.com/izupe3

Comment: Your actual code is different than what you posted here. Next time please post the actual code you're using. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that the default behavior of the `a` element is firing and reloading the page.

Parent should still work, because the event is on the `<dd>`.

Try this:

```
$("#posters dd").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent_padding = $(this).find("img").attr("height");
    $(this).parent().css({"padding-top":parent_padding});
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Looking at your code, it is quite different from what you posted.

There are several issues.

I don't think `end()` is being used properly (not sure though).

`prev()` shouldn't accept a function as an argument.

Gave up after that.

***Posted code from link provided:***

***Just so it is clear, the code example below is not a solution. It is the actual code that you are using (based on the link you provided). I did nothing to correct it. I'm just making the point that it would be extremely helpful if you would post the actual code you're using in your question instead of a modified version. As it turns out, your modified version in the question eliminated the error(s).***

```
$("dt").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings()
             .removeClass("active")
             .end()
        .prev(function(){
                    $("dd").parent()
                        .css({'padding-top':$(this).find('img').height()});
    }).andSelf().addClass("active")});
    $("#posters dt").fadeTo("fast",.7);$("#posters dt").hover(function(){$(this).fadeTo("fast",.9)},function(){$(this).fadeTo("fast",.7)});
                                                                         $("#posters .toggle a").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('active');$("#posters dt").toggle();return false});
  });
```

In the future, please post the code you're actually using. In this case, you modified out the error. Had you posted the actual event handler, you would have had an immediate solution.

---

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:**

This is the beginning of a solution.

You were assigning events inside of the click event handler. This is not right, so I just removed them. I'll consider those to be a separate issue for now.

This (as far as I can tell) will do what you want with the padding. Please notice that your click event is on the `dt` and not the `dd`, since that is how you had it in your code.

If the event should be on the `dd`, then change it to `#('posters dd').click(...` and get rid of `next()` on the next line down.

```
$("#posters dt").click(function(){
    var padding = $(this).next().find('img').attr('height');
    $(this)
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent()
        .css({'padding-top':padding});
}); ​
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of getting the image's `.attr('height')` you can always just use the jQuery function [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height).

Other than that, it should adjust your padding-top appropriately.

[jsbin preview](http://jsbin.com/exizi4/2)

Comment: @gnarf - No offense, but using `height()` was never a solution since the `height` attribute was explicitly set, and the OP was still having issues.

Answer (score 3):

Although your syntax is correct, trying to set a property can be set like this as well.
    .css(property, value);

**Example**

```
$(this).parent().css("padding-top", parent_padding);

$(this).css("color","red");
```

Reference and more examples: [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: `css({"padding-top":parent_padding}` is valid, it can take more than one property: `css({"padding-top":parent_padding,color:'red'}`

Comment: doesn't work. Watched through firebug, seems that it cant catch the parent tag - <dl>

Comment: Where's the `<dd>` with the id of posters?

Answer (score 1):

### Updated:

```
$("#posters dd").click(function(){
    var parent_padding = $(this).find("img").height();
    $(this).closest("dl").css("padding-top",parent_padding);
});
```

Comment: So you you condemn my answer, then answer with the exact same thing. You're very sharp there chief.

Comment: @gmcalab. Sorry, but no. I changed `.attr("height")` to `.height()`.

Comment: Wasn't talking about that line dude.

Comment: fixed the topic, it should catch 'dl parent', not an actual 'parent'.

Comment: @gmcaleb: You were suggesting that using `("property":"value"}` was causing a problem, which it was not. The reason I changed in my answer is because it is pointless to use the `{}` syntax when the `property, value` arguments work fine.

Comment: @D M - Actually, I corrected myself saying the syntax is correct. But also provided the alternative `property,value` method. I know this method works fine, that's why I originally suggested trying it.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML there's no element with the id `posters`, although that's what your selector is searching. Long shot, but maybe that's the problem? The rest of the code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: there is #posters, forgot to mention. Thanks.